# Visual studio 2015 debugging with older dlls

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, dll

I'm trying to debug the [sample application](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html#test-it) from OpenCV under Windows 10 - Visual Studio 2015.

I have already configured Visual Studio according to the OpenCV wiki and I can compile the application and run it fine.

The issue I'm having is when I try to debug the application. I'm getting that the program can't be started because `MSVCP120D.dll` is missing. I have already installed the Visual C++ 2013 redistributables from Microsoft, however they don't come with the debugging dlls.

The issue probably stems from the fact that the OpenCV version I'm using (`D:\opencv\opencv\build\x64\vc12`) was compiled with 2013. Is there a way to get the debugger version of this dll? Or start the debugger without it? Or am I stuck having to recompile OpenCV with 2015?

Thanks.

Comment: in your project settings you can select the used compiler. Choose vc120. But maybe you'll have to install the compiler first if it isn't delivered with visual studio 2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or am I stuck having to recompile OpenCV with 2015?

You probably are since it is a really bad idea to mix different runtime dlls. In your case you're mixing your compiled program (MSVC 2015) with the OpenCV dlls (MSVC 2013).

You should do either of these:

1. Compile your program with MVSC 2013, which I believe will require you to install MSVC 2013 on your machine
2. Compile OpenCV using MSVC 2015.

Note: This is probably gonna be better with programs compiled with MSVC 2015 and later compilers because of the [Universal CRT](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt.aspx)